How can i use ggplot's scale_x_sqrt function for stacked barplots?
I created a stacked horizontal bar plot using ggplot, and the plot works well with a continuous x-axis. This resulted in the following figure:

However, since my data spans a wide range—from 0 to over 100,000—smaller bars become almost invisible. To address this, I switched the x-axis to a square root scale by using scale_x_sqrt instead of scale_x_continuous. While this improves the visibility of smaller bars, I encountered an issue:

The labels are no longer properly aligned with the bars,
and the values displayed on the plot do not match the axis ticks.

This is the picture I end up with:

What is going on here? Why does this not work out of the box? For a similar non-stacked barplot this works fine, but the problem seems to be that I want to apply it to a stacked barplot. Does anyone know if there is a way to fix this issue? Or am I perhaps better of using another way of displaying my data?
For reference, this is my code for creating the second plot (note that the only difference to my first plot is using scale_x_sqrt instead of scale_x_continuous. Also I posted some a subset of the data so you will not get the exact same appearance, but the problem is still there.):
# Load data
structure(list(Zielorganismus = c("Blattlaeuse", "Schnellkaefer", 
"Moosknopfkaefer", "Blattlaeuse", "Moosknopfkaefer", "Getreidehaehnchen", 
"Schnellkaefer", "Erdfloehe", "Erdfloehe", "Getreidehaehnchen"
), Merkmal = c("Anz. Tiere pro Kreuzfensterfalle", "Anz. Tiere pro Kreuzfensterfalle", 
"Anz. Tiere pro Kreuzfensterfalle", "Anz. Tiere pro Barber-Falle", 
"Anz. Tiere pro Barber-Falle", "Anz. Tiere pro Kreuzfensterfalle", 
"Anz. Tiere pro Barber-Falle", "Anz. Tiere pro Barber-Falle", 
"Anz. Tiere pro Kreuzfensterfalle", "Anz. Tiere pro Barber-Falle"
), my_sum1 = c(10639, 10114, 3401, 3127, 634, 472, 430, 275, 
187, 119)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -10L), groups = structure(list(Zielorganismus = c("Blattlaeuse", 
"Erdfloehe", "Getreidehaehnchen", "Moosknopfkaefer", "Schnellkaefer"
), .rows = structure(list(c(1L, 4L), 8:9, c(6L, 10L), c(3L, 5L
), c(2L, 7L)), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -5L), .drop = TRUE))

ggplot(data = sum_Tiere_Merkmal, aes(x = my_sum1, y = Zielorganismus, fill = Merkmal)) +
  # Create stacked bar plot
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "stack") +
  
  # Apply square root scale for x-axis
  scale_x_sqrt(
   # labels = scales::number_format(accuracy = 1), 
    limits = c(0, NA),
               name = "Anzahl Individuen (Gesamtsummen, sqrt)") + 

For completeness sake, I use a bunch of modifiers to add more information to the graph, but that might not be of relevance to the question.
  scale_y_discrete(name = "Artengruppen (Funktionelle Gruppen)",
                   labels = c("Diptera" = "Fliegen_sonstige", 
                              "Hymenoptera" = "Hautflügler_sonstige",
                              "Symphyta" = "Pflanzenwespen",
                              "Kaefer_allg" = "Käfer_sonstige", 
                              "Myriapoda" = "Hundert/-tausendfüßer")) +
  
  # Define color palette for different 'Merkmal'
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("darkseagreen4", "darkseagreen3"))+
  
 # Add total sums at the end of each bar plot, with nudge to the right
  geom_text(data = total_sum, aes(x = total, y = Zielorganismus, label = total),
            inherit.aes = FALSE, hjust = -0.2, vjust = 0.5, size = 5, color = "black") +

  # Apply clean theme
  theme_classic() +
  
  # Remove legend for 'Merkmal' (optional)
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  
  # Customize axis and title text sizes for clarity
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = 16),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 16),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12),
        plot.title = element_text(size = 22))


Could you please share some reproducible code and data using dput?

@Quinten thanks for the tipp! I added some data using dput.

From the ?position_stack: "Because stacking is performed after scale transformations, stacking with non-linear scales gives distortions that easily lead to misinterpretations of the data. It is therefore discouraged to use these position adjustments in combination with scale transformations, such as logarithmic or square root scales."

Thanks for the insight, then I think I will not be able to visualize the data in this way. Thanks for the help everyone!

You could do
ggplot(data = sum_Tiere_Merkmal, aes(x = sqrt(my_sum1), y = Zielorganismus, fill = Merkmal)) +
  # Create stacked bar plot
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "stack") +
  geom_text(aes(label = my_sum1), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))+
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 200),
                     breaks = sqrt(0:10*10000),
                     labels = as.character(0:10*10000)
                     )+
  labs(x = "Anzahl Individuen (Gesamtsummen)")

but to be honest, I think that's a terribly confusing way to show that data.

Thanks for your answer, how would you propose to visualize the data instead?

Dodge, don't stack things on a non-linear axis.
